# Alternative to JCA

Tags: tomcat, resources, adapter, jca

Is there an alternative to JCA(resource adapter) that works on tomcat instead of application server?

Comment: What kind of problem do you want to solve? Which parts of JCA do you need?
Knowing this we can maybe dig up an idea of where you should go.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try JBI Binding Component, JBI is another java specification for application integration.

But IBM and BEA(now Oracle) does not support JBI.